# Удаление чисел Фибоначчи из массива

Tags: c, числа-фибоначчи

Вот вся программа на удаление чисел Фибоначчи, только возникла проблема надо чтобы в массиве выводились и отрицательные элементы, а у меня не получается.....

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

char* Rus(const char* text);

int fibonacci (int, int [100]);

int main(){
 srand(time(NULL));

int a[100];
int n,i,j;
int fibonacci (int, int [100]);
cout <<Rus("Введите количество элементов: ") << endl;
    cin>>n;
cout << Rus("Исходный массив: ")<< endl;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        a[i]=rand()%30+5;
        rand()%100-rand()%100;
        cout << a[i]<<" ";
        }
fibonacci (n, a);
getch();
}

int fibonacci (int n, int a[100])
{
int q[100];
int max, g, b,i,j,c;
max=a[0];
    for (i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
        if (max<a[i])
         max=a[i];
        }
g=0;
b=1;
    for (i=0;b<=max;i++)
       {
       c=g+b;
       g=b;
       b=c;
       q[i]=b;
       }
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << Rus("Ряд Фибоначчи: ")<< endl;
    for (j=0;j<i;j++)
      cout<< q[j] << " ";

         for (i=0;i<max;i++)
                for (j=0;j<n;j++)
                        if (q[i]==a[j])
                        {
                        for (b=j;b<n-1;b++)
                         a[b]=a[b+1];
                         n=n-1;
                         j--;
                        }
cout << endl;
cout << Rus("Новый массив: ")<< endl;
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
                cout<<a[i]<<" ";
return 0;
}
char bufRus[256];
char* Rus(const char* text)
{
CharToOem(text,bufRus);
return bufRus;
}
```

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под удалением числа из массива ? Замена его на (скажем 0) или сдвиг чисел правее данного на одну позицию влево ? А с последними что делать ? Массив как в этой программе или динамический (из кучи) ?

Comment: я подразумеваю сдвиг чисел правее данного на одну позицию влево.Размер массива уменьшить после удаления (--n)Массивы реализовать как псевдодинамические, их размерности передавать как параметры функций.

Comment: @Neon, Вы на полпути к решению. 

Смотрите, программа вычисляющая числа Фибоначчи у Вас есть. Осталось преобразовать ее в **функцию** (скажем int isFibo (int num)), которая проверяет свой аргумент, является ли он числом Фибоначчи.

Осталось написать функцию void shiftarr (int a[], int asize, int from) и тривиальный цикл в котором перебираете элементы массива, для каждого вызываете isFibo() и если надо shiftarr(), не забывая менять asize, который является границей цикла.

IMHO часа через два-три Вас можно будет плюсовать (по результатам **написанной Вами** программы).

Comment: объясните плиз что такое void shiftarr (int a[], int asize, int from)? я такое еще не встречал...пока новичок

Comment: Это функция, которую Вам предстоит написать. Она должна сдвигать элементы в массиве размером asize на 1 влево, начиная с индекса from.

Т.е. a[from] = a[from+1] и т.д. Естественно, последний сдвигаемый это a[asize-1].

Нетрудно сообразить, что Вам надо вызывать ее для тех индексов, где лежат числа Фибоначчи.

А функцию isFibo() уже написали ?

Comment: еще не написал...

Comment: программа написана выше, когда у меня уберут -1!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще вариант

```
int
isFibo (int k)
{
  if (k < 0)
    return 0;
  if (k == 0)
    return 1;

  int f0 = 1, f = 1, x;
  while (f > 0 && f < k) { // f > 0 для проверки переполнения
    x = f+f0;
    f0 = f;
    f = x;
  }
  return f == k;
}
```

Интересно, на практике какой быстрее ?

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот, например. Изначально вектор *fib должен содержать хотя бы два значения: 0 и 1.

```
int isFibo( vector<int> *fib, int k) {
    if(fib->back() < k) {
        while(fib->back() < k) {
            int n = fib->size();
            fib->push_back((*fib)[n-1] + (*fib)[n-2]);
        }
        return k==fib->back();
    } else {
        int i1=0, i2=fib->size() - 1;
        if((*fib)[i1] == k || (*fib)[i2] == k) return 1;
        while(i2 > i1+1) {
            int i=(i1+i2)/2;
            if((*fib)[i] == k) return 1;
            else if ((*fib)[i] < k) i1=i;
            else i2=i;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```